# need assistance with tic tac toe issue in python

Tags: python

```
XO=["X", "O"]

if Kord[0] == XO and Kord[1] == XO and Kord[2] == XO\

or Kord[3] == XO and Kord[4] == XO and Kord[5] == XO\

or Kord[6] == XO and Kord[7] == XO and Kord[8] == XO:

print "done"
```

how do i make it so that IF there is an "X" OR an "O" in all Kord 0-8 then it will print hello.

this is for a game called tic tac toe

Answer (score 0):

If you meant, all the indices have either "O" or "X"

```
if all(currentKord in XO for currentKord in Kord):
  print "hello"
```

If you meant, all the indices have the same value, either "X" or "O"

```
if "".join(Kord) in ["XXXXXXXXX", "OOOOOOOO"]:
  print "hello"
```